# Old domain pointed to new domain via A record gives SSL error

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

Here's my situation. olddomain.com is pointed at `newdomain.com's` server IP address via an A record. When a user types in olddomain.com, the are taken to newdomain.com and ultimately end up at `https://www.newdomain.com`. Where I am having trouble is that when a user goes to https://oldomain.com, they are presented with a security error saying that `oldomain.com's` security certificate is from newdomain.com. However, if I type in `https://www.olddomain.com`, it gets forwarded to https://www.newdomain .com with no problem or error. What do I need to do to fix this? olddomain.com is not added as a SAN on my SSL. Do I need to do this? Is there a DNS change I need to make? I don't have the option of using a basic forward from olddomain.com to newdomain.com and can't see any glaring issues with my DNS settings. I'm running on an Apache server setup on AWS with Incapsula handling security and CDN.

Comment: It sounds like olddomain.com doesn't have the same IP address as www.olddomain.com. www prefixes are usually a CNAME record pointing to olddomain.com. I'd check that first.

Comment: Your certificate at `www.oldomain.com` needs to have both `www.oldomain.com` and `oldomain.com` as allowed names. Otherwise the redirect won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is an [issue of www and non-www domain name](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/do-i-need-different-ssl-certificates-for-www-non-www-domain). If your domain is secured with multi-domain (SAN) SSL certificate then you must have to add your one more domain name olddomain.com into it for avoiding SSL errors when anyone will access your domain '**olddomain.com**' via https://olddomain.com.

SSL certificate authorities like RapidSSL and GeoTrust are providing features to secure www and non-www domain with only one SSL certificate, so if your requirement is to secure single domain then you don't want to take multi-domain security.